# How to use sass --precision?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am trying to use sass + compass to make a fluid grid and I need my %'s to have at least 8 digits when compute them out but right now sass + compass is rounding my decimals to 3-digits. I found that if use `--precision` you can tell sass to round to how ever many digits you want, my issue is that i can seem to figure out how to get `--precision` to work from the terminal on my project. Please help

Comment: check this article out: http://heygrady.com/blog/2012/04/20/compass-grid-gem-and-new-fluid-grid/

Comment: really dosent tlk about adjusting rounding in compass or sass, i need a way to change the rounding, which --precision ishould do but i just cant get it to work

Answer (score 5):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672473/sass-and-rounding-down-numbers-can-this-be-configured), configuring @precision in SASS's numbers.rb will achieve this result.  It appears that --precision is nonfunctional.

Comment: Where is this numbers.rb?

Comment: In Windows, you can find it at `Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\sass-3.4.21\lib\sass\script\value`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sass --precision 6 input.scss output.css
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10369785