# Bootstrap SASS Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

I am keen to use the new Bootstrap SASS however I have noticed that a precision value has to be added to continue. I am aware of this bug and how it benefits the project.

However I am unsure how to build this into my project, the Bootstrap Docs are pretty lacking here..

```
::Sass::Script::Number.precision = [10, ::Sass::Script::Number.precision].max
```

This was the code given above and link here - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

I would note that I have already installed downloaded the gem and installed it using bower. Just need to get this code a place to call home!

Comment: You have the ruby on rails tag but you're installing the 'gem' via Bower? Did you use Bower to install or Rubygems?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the one-liner in application.rb

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/409

Comment: I am planning to use compass, could I negate an application.rb and use it here..?

Comment: Could this page help? [How to use sass --precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374438/how-to-use-sass-precision)

Comment: I was going to install Grunt worry about later. Then Codekit 2 supports this a global setting change win!. Thanks @yoppuyoppu for the reply!