# How to get the long version of a calculated result with SASS

Tags: css, sass

In sass I am doing this:

```
#myid
  width: (500 / 960) /*also need to convert it to % 
                     (* 100%) but that works fine*/
}
```

And the result that I am getting is:

```
#myid{
  width: 0.521;
}
```

Now on the 'responsive web design' book it states that we should not shorten the result. So what I needed is

```
  #myid{
      width: 0.52083333333333;
    }
```

So is there a way to get the full result in this case, with sass?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369643/rounding-in-sass ?

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo thanks that's what I need, do you know how I can accomplish this with CodeKit? as I could not set sass and compass using the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Add this near the end of your `config.rb`:

```
Sass::Script::Number.precision = 13
```